# Vite: Is it possible to move all tool configuration files to a subdirectory or to a single JavaScript file

Tags: vite

So I have a ton of configuration files:

```
.eslintrc.js
index.html
package.json
tsconfig.json
index.d.ts
vite.config.js
```

While I'm pretty sure this all could somehow be stuffed in package.json (and some of it even is), the advantages of JavaScript configuration files aren't to be overlooked.

I've done some searching, but found nothing on the subject. This suggests that everyone (else) is content with this and they are not bothered with configuration files polluting the root directory of a project. I would prefer to keep just the "relevant" stuff in there, e.g. licenses, docs, app entry point, etc.

So, is there a way I could stuff all of the above into one JavaScript file or into a subdirectory, keeping existing UX for building and serving (running commands from root folder)?

Comment: Have you figured this out since?

Comment: No, I have not. Instead, we're now using workspaces / monorepo that introduce even more such files. Not without (many) issues, though. All to achieve a semblance of what we want.

Comment: Thanks for the update. From my research it seems that it's not possible, and having Vite's config file at the root of the project is required.